# Angular4 component state

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I have an Angular 4 application that currently has two components, CompA and CompB. CompA is fetching books through a http service and displaying it in a table. CompB is just showing some static data. I am navigating between these two components. The problem is when CompA is done fetching data and I navigate to CompB and then come back to CompA, it again fetches the data through http service. This way, I'm sending back to back requests to server. Is there any generic way to tackle this issue? I'm developing a big application and that application have a lot of such components.

Answer (score 2):

Your best approach would be to have the http call and local caching of it's output in a service. The component will request the data from this service when it is required and the service will keep it's state during the lifetime of the application.

Comment: What if the new book gets inserted in backend (from where I'm fetching the data) during application life cycle, will I still be able to see that newly inserted book in my component?

Comment: You'll have to decide when to make a new request and when you use your previous result. This could be a timeout or a trigger. If you're using API calls you won't know for sure unless you request new data. The alternative way you can push data to your application from the backend is by setting up a websocket. Regardless you'll want to manage your http call and the caching in a service.